# linux shell to accept parameters

Tags: linux, shell

I need help writing a dynamic shell script to move files from a folder to another(WORK). I have a folder (FOLDER_A) with files that will be moved to a folder(WORK). The name of folder_A changes every week, so in week 1, it's FOLDER_A; in week 2, it may be called FOLDER_B; in week 3, it's called something else. However, the folder (WORK) is static, that is, the name never changes. The folder simply serves as a destination folder where files from the folders(FOLDER_A, FOLDER_B and so on) are moved to.

I would like to script that accepts parameters (input), and once the entered, the script then triggers a move process from the source folder to the destination folder (WORK). Thanks for your help

Comment: http://www.freelancer.com/

Comment: Read manual pages for inotify, rsync and bash and you can write something pretty powerful in 3 lines

Answer (score 0):

```
WORK=/work/folder

while [ ! -d $source ]; do 
    read -p 'move from where?: ' source; 
done
mv $source $WORK
```

## presto!

---

*You seem very confused about the problem. Try drawing what you need on paper, then writing it in 50 words or less. Also, you should be asking about specific problems that you are having with a script that you have written.*